# Conditional concat in RXJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two streams :

```
const sourceOne = of(1, 2, 3);
const sourceTwo = of(4, 5, 6);
const example = sourceOne.pipe(concat(sourceTwo)); //123456
```

As you see  , I've concatenated them unconditionally.

But it turns out that I need to concat them only if the first item from `sourceOne` is "even". (`%2==0`)

**Question:**

How can I concat `sourceTwo` to `sourceOne` by adding conditions regarding the first stream ?

*I know I can create an external method which will be piped , but I don't think it's the RXJS way of doing it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `sourceOne` is a cold Observables, as in your example, then you can try something along these lines

```
const example = sourceOne.pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(d => d % 2 === 0 ? sourceOne.pipe(concat(sourceTwo)) : empty()),
)
```

If instead `sourceOne` is a hot Observable, you can try something like this

```
const sourceOneHot = of(1, 2, 3).pipe(share());
const exampleHot = sourceOneHot.pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(d => d % 2 === 0 ? concat(of(d), sourceOneHot, sourceTwo) : empty()),
);
```

To create a hot source Observable you can use

Comment: I think you mean `switchMap(d => d % 2 ? sourceOne : sourceOne.pipe(concat(sourceTwo)))` or `switchMap(d => sourceOne.pipe(concat(d % 2 ?empty() : sourceTwo)))`. Your version shows either concatenated arrays (for even d) or nothing (for odd d)

Comment: I understand this is the requirement: nothing is emitted if the first element of `sourceOne` is null.

Comment: ^ Right. but if the first stream has a first "odd" value ,  emit only it. , otherwise , emit also the second stream