# Angular - run SwitchMap on condition

Tags: angular, if-statement, switchmap

I have the code below:

```
data$ = getResponse1$.pipe(
        tap((res1: any) => {
          this.qService.data = res1;
        }),
        switchMap(() =>
          of(getResponse2$(res2)).pipe(
            map((val) => {
              const res: any = {
                val,
              };
              return res;
            })
          )
        )
      );
```

Is it possible to run getResponse1$ i.e. the first observable, along with getResponse2$
only when a condition is true?
Otherwise, I want to execute only getResponse2$.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the exact desired behaviour is? What should be emitted by this Observable and under which circumstances?

Comment: what is the condition

Comment: @WillAlexander I want to handle the data of a tree. If the level of the current node is 1, I want to run both observables. If the level of the current node is > 1, I want to execute only the second observable, i.e. getResponse2$.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal if(level === 1) I want to run the code mentioned above. If(level > 1) I want to run the second part of the code above i.e. only getResponse2$. I wanted to avoid writing twice the code in an if..else block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at: [Conditional concat in RXJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622499/conditional-concat-in-rxjs)

Adopting it to your case:

```
getResponse2$.pipe(
  switchMap(response => [your_condition] ? of(response).pipe(withLatestFrom(getResponse1$)) : of(response))
);
```

You will get an array as output if condition is true, where the first element of array corresponds to `getResponse2$` result value, and second one to `getResponse2$`. Otherwise you will get just `getResponse2$` result value.